# How to insert 10 million rows into MySQL database with Knex.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to insert 10M+ rows into a MySQL database using Knex.js. Is there a way to use a for loop to insert arrays of length 10000 (which seems to maximum size that I am able to insert - anything larger than that gets "Error: ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes").

I tried using a promise chain but the chain would be very long to accommodate 10M records.

```
exports.seed = (knex) => {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('books').del()
    .then(() => {
      const fakeBooks = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
        fakeBooks.push(createFakeBooks());
      }
      return knex('books').insert(fakeBooks)
        .then(() => {
          const fakeBooks1 = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
            fakeBooks1.push(createFakeBooks());
          }
          return knex('books').insert(fakeBooks1)
            .then(() => {
              const fakeBooks2 = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
                fakeBooks2.push(createFakeBooks());
              }
...
```

Comment: How about a recursive function which will call itself in `.then()` until the array is empty?

Answer (score 5):

You can use https://knexjs.org/#Utility-BatchInsert which is done for inserting big amount of rows to DB.

```
await knex.batchInsert('books', create10MFakeBooks(), 5000)
```

However you might want to actually create those books in smaller batches to prevent using gigabytes of memory. So MikaS's answer is valid, that just use async / await and it will be trivial to write.

I would not use knex for this kind of job, but raw SQL.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier if you use `async` and `await` and ditch the `then`s. It can then be written like this:

```
exports.seed = async (knex) => {
    await knex('books').del();

    let fakeBooks = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10000000; i += 1) {
      fakeBooks.push(createFakeBooks());

      if (i % 1000 === 0) {
        await knex('books').insert(fakeBooks);
        fakeBooks = [];
      }
    }
};
```

`await` will make the promise finish before the function continues, without blocking the thread. The loop will run ten million times and insert into the database for every 1000 rows. You can change it to 10000 rows, but you might as well use 1000 to be sure.

I only tried with one million rows myself, as it took too much time to insert ten million.