# bulk or batch update in knex.js

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js

I'm working with on nodejs with knex.js and sql as a database I have a record of 4000 data in array of object I have to update it into a table, which is currently taking more than 10 minutes. I wanted to reduce the time taken.

this is the records

```
      const records = [
        { ID: "45159", UnitCost: "1", country: "GB" },
        { ID: "45209", UnitCost: "2", country: "GB" },
      ];
```

currently I'm mapping through each record and writing this condition

```
      const response = await baseQueryBuilder
        .clone()
        .where("country", countryCode)
        .where({ID:id})
        .update({UnitCost:UnitCost});
```

is there any method that we can do batch or bulk upload so that the time can be reduced. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert 10 million rows into MySQL database with Knex.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225403/how-to-insert-10-million-rows-into-mysql-database-with-knex-js)

Comment: No I only show for insert, I wanted to update and knex doesn't have a utility like batchInsert.

Comment: there iw no fast way, what you can do is divide the updates in smaller chunks and update n a loop, but in endeffect build a prepared statement and let it look like the bulk insert does, the principle is the same